# Unable to sendkeys/type email in google login popup window [ JAVA - selenium ]

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver, error-handling

```
 `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://selinium jar driver//driver/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
//        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://auth.acciojob.com/");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href=\'/login\']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='login-btns email-btn']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
          //-------------------------- setting up pop wind -------------------------------------
          Set<String> windows= driver.getWindowHandles();
          Iterator<String> it = windows.iterator();
          String p = it.next();                     // p knows parent wind
          String c = it.next();                    // another window
          driver.switchTo().window(c);             //switch parent win to child window
          Thread.sleep(3000);                
  
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys("abcde@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Next']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("qqwertyuiop1234567890");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Next']")).click();`

i was able to reach login with google popup window but not able to type in it useing sendkeys help....
[syntax is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxJUs.png)
```

**i was able to reach login with google popup window but not able to type in it useing sendkeys help....**
**i geeting these error**

> 

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type='email']"}
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.125)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after the webdriver instantiation. It looks like 1s is not enough for the page to load:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```